# Calculate pullup resistor, cat5e ftp

Tags: i2c

[image]let me describe my schema, i got one arduino and one esp32 connected over i2c using 30m cat 5e ftp cable, I'm using 12v to power up both devices, each of them have dc-dc converter that convert to 5V, there is two P82B715P extenders, controllers i2c bus is wired with 10K pullups to P82B715P , i2c bus between P82B715P is wired with 1K pullups on master device side. On 30M cable it works only if I transmit SDA, SCL in twister pair with ground, no power voltage (+12V) is on the cable. When I place +12V on the cable, I2C bus stop working, tried to decrease pullups to 0.4K no effect, since I do not understand can only make try/fail tests. Question is do I need to adjust pullups beween P82B715P only,  or I need to change pullups between P82B715P and esp/arduino? Perhaps for calculation of pullups I must mention that i2c bus work on 10KHz

[image]

Comment: Can you post a schematic? Your question is a little hard to understand. Help us to help you. :)

Comment: Well I do not have schematic, gonna try to draw one later

Comment: Check VCC and pullup calculation. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/p82b715.pdf

Comment: Using the formula and the remark in the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/P82B715.pdf) (8.1.1), I get between 330 and 660 Ohm for the 30m cable. Are you getting a stable 5V on the otherside of the cat5 cable; from the dc-dc converter?

Comment: yes voltage is stable, just I2c not working if +12V is on same cable where data is.

Comment: you run the 12 V twisted with SDA?

Comment: I tried all combination, with GND with 12V nothing make it work, and decide to stop trying and go to RS485

Comment: @user3503519 did you put adequate capacitors on the 12V line, on both sides? This looks like interference between the 12V noise and the data wires..

Comment: DC DC convertors include capacitors